# How can I generate a keyup event with a specific keycode in IE8?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, keyboard-events

I need to generate keyup events in IE 8 using native DOM functions (no jQuery). The following code generates, fires, and receives the event, but the keyCode is always 0. How do I properly pass the keyCode?

```
<form><input id="me" type="submit" /></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var me = document.getElementById("me");
me.attachEvent("onkeyup", function(e) {
  alert(e.keyCode); // => 0
});

document.getElementById("me").fireEvent('onkeyup', 13);
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out. The solution is to create an event object, assign the keycode, and fire it from the node.

```
var e = document.createEventObject("KeyboardEvent");
e.keyCode = keyCode;

node.fireEvent("onkeyup", e);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing your sol'n. For reference, in jQuery it would amount to: `e = jQuery.Event("keyup"); e.keyCode = 13; $(node).trigger(e);`

Comment: From IE9 forward and for all other browsers you use createEvent() and dispatchEvent() rather than createEventObject and fireEvent(). The leading 'on' in the event name is also dropped. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/921640

Comment: It is not clear how do you define the element to trigger the event. Could you please explain it or extend the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev it can be any element gotten via `document.getElementById` or similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
e = e || window.event;
keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

That will make events work in all browsers.
Also, I prefer to use `me.onkeyup = function(e) { ... }`, but that' just personal preference (I know the drawbacks of this method, but I have clever ways to work around them)

Comment: Both `e` and `e.keyCode` are defined so that code doesn't change `e` in any way. Unfortunately, `e.keyCode` comes in set to `0`. Am I passing the `13` properly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `fireEvent()`, but I don't think so. It seems more like you're passing an extra argument to the function.